# Insert timer in slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was developing a slider for a website but don't know how to put it on auto mode so that the slider slides automatically. I just want that the slider will change panels automatically after a certain amount of time please help me.

`

;( function( window ) {

```
'use strict';

// based on http://responsejs.com/labs/dimensions/
function getViewport(axis) {
    var client, inner;
    if( axis === 'x' ) {
        client = docElem['clientWidth'];
        inner = window['innerWidth'];
    }
    else if( axis === 'y' ) {
        client = docElem['clientHeight'];
        inner = window['innerHeight'];
    }

    return client < inner ? inner : client;
}

var docElem = window.document.documentElement,
    transEndEventNames = {
        'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd',
        'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
        'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd',
        'msTransition': 'MSTransitionEnd',
        'transition': 'transitionend'
    },
    transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ],
    support = { transitions : Modernizr.csstransitions },
    win = { width : getViewport('x'), height : getViewport('y') };

function extend( a, b ) {
    for( var key in b ) { 
        if( b.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
            a[key] = b[key];
        }
    }
    return a;
}

function BoxesFx( el, options ) {   
    this.el = el;
    this.options = extend( {}, this.options );
    extend( this.options, options );
    this._init();
}

BoxesFx.prototype.options = {}

BoxesFx.prototype._init = function() {
    // set transforms configuration
    this._setTransforms();
    // which effect
    this.effect = this.el.getAttribute( 'data-effect' ) || 'effect-1';
    // check if animating
    this.isAnimating = false;
    // the panels
    this.panels = [].slice.call( this.el.querySelectorAll( '.panel' ) );
    // total number of panels (4 for this demo)
    //this.panelsCount = this.panels.length;
    this.panelsCount = 4;
    // current panel´s index
    this.current = 0;
    classie.add( this.panels[0], 'current' );
    // replace image with 4 divs, each including the image
    var self = this;
    this.panels.forEach( function( panel ) {
        var img = panel.querySelector( 'img' ), imgReplacement = '';
        for( var i = 0; i < self.panelsCount; ++i ) {
            imgReplacement += '<div class="bg-tile"><div class="bg-img"><img src="' + img.src + '" /></div></div>'
        }
        panel.removeChild( img );
        panel.innerHTML = imgReplacement + panel.innerHTML;
    } );
    // add navigation element
    this.nav = document.createElement( 'nav' );
    this.nav.innerHTML = '<span class="prev"><i></i></span><span class="next"><i></i></span>';
    this.el.appendChild( this.nav );
    // initialize events
    this._initEvents();
}

// set the transforms per effect
// we have defined both the next and previous action transforms for each panel
BoxesFx.prototype._setTransforms = function() {
    this.transforms = {
        'effect-1' : {
            'next' : [
                'translate3d(0, ' + (win.height/2+10) + 'px, 0)', // transforms for 1 panel
                'translate3d(-' + (win.width/2+10) + 'px, 0, 0)', // transforms for 2 panel
                'translate3d(' + (win.width/2+10) + 'px, 0, 0)', // transforms for 3 panel
                'translate3d(0, -' + (win.height/2+10) + 'px, 0)' // transforms for 4 panel
            ],
            'prev' : [
                'translate3d(' + (win.width/2+10) + 'px, 0, 0)',
                'translate3d(0, ' + (win.height/2+10) + 'px, 0)',
                'translate3d(0, -' + (win.height/2+10) + 'px, 0)',
                'translate3d(-' + (win.width/2+10) + 'px, 0, 0)'
            ]
        },
        'effect-2' : {
            'next' : [
                'translate3d(-' + (win.width/2+10) + 'px, 0, 0)',
                'translate3d(' + (win.width/2+10) + 'px, 0, 0)',
                'translate3d(-' + (win.width/2+10) + 'px, 0, 0)',
                'translate3d(' + (win.width/2+10) + 'px, 0, 0)'
            ],
            'prev' : [
                'translate3d(0,-' + (win.height/2+10) + 'px, 0)',
                'translate3d(0,-' + (win.height/2+10) + 'px, 0)',
                'translate3d(0,' + (win.height/2+10) + 'px, 0)',
                'translate3d(0,' + (win.height/2+10) + 'px, 0)'
            ]
        },
        'effect-3' : {
            'next' : [
                'translate3d(0,' + (win.height/2+10) + 'px, 0)',
                'translate3d(0,' + (win.height/2+10) + 'px, 0)',
                'translate3d(0,' + (win.height/2+10) + 'px, 0)',
                'translate3d(0,' + (win.height/2+10) + 'px, 0)'
            ],
            'prev' : [
                'translate3d(0,-' + (win.height/2+10) + 'px, 0)',
                'translate3d(0,-' + (win.height/2+10) + 'px, 0)',
                'translate3d(0,-' + (win.height/2+10) + 'px, 0)',
                'translate3d(0,-' + (win.height/2+10) + 'px, 0)'
            ]
        }
    };  
}

BoxesFx.prototype._initEvents = function() {
    var self = this, navctrls = this.nav.children;
    // previous action
    navctrls[0].addEventListener( 'click', function() { self._navigate('prev') } );
    // next action
    navctrls[1].addEventListener( 'click', function() { self._navigate('next') } );
    // window resize
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', function() { self._resizeHandler(); } );
}

// goto next or previous slide
BoxesFx.prototype._navigate = function( dir ) {
    if( this.isAnimating ) return false;
    this.isAnimating = true;

    var self = this, currentPanel = this.panels[ this.current ];

    if( dir === 'next' ) {
        this.current = this.current < this.panelsCount - 1 ? this.current + 1 : 0;          
    }
    else {
        this.current = this.current > 0 ? this.current - 1 : this.panelsCount - 1;
    }

    // next panel to be shown
    var nextPanel = this.panels[ this.current ];
    // add class active to the next panel to trigger its animation
    classie.add( nextPanel, 'active' );
    // apply the transforms to the current panel
    this._applyTransforms( currentPanel, dir );

    // let´s track the number of transitions ended per panel
    var cntTransTotal = 0,

        // transition end event function
        onEndTransitionFn = function( ev ) {
            if( ev && !classie.has( ev.target, 'bg-img' ) ) return false;

            // return if not all panel transitions ended
            ++cntTransTotal;
            if( cntTransTotal < self.panelsCount ) return false;

            if( support.transitions ) {
                this.removeEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
            }

            // remove current class from current panel and add it to the next one
            classie.remove( currentPanel, 'current' );
            classie.add( nextPanel, 'current' );
            // reset transforms for the currentPanel
            self._resetTransforms( currentPanel );
            // remove class active
            classie.remove( nextPanel, 'active' );
            self.isAnimating = false;
        };

    if( support.transitions ) {
        currentPanel.addEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
    }
    else {
        onEndTransitionFn();
    }
}

BoxesFx.prototype._applyTransforms = function( panel, dir ) {
    var self = this;
    [].slice.call( panel.querySelectorAll( 'div.bg-img' ) ).forEach( function( tile, pos ) {
        tile.style.WebkitTransform = self.transforms[self.effect][dir][pos];
        tile.style.transform = self.transforms[self.effect][dir][pos];
    } );
}

BoxesFx.prototype._resetTransforms = function( panel ) {
    [].slice.call( panel.querySelectorAll( 'div.bg-img' ) ).forEach( function( tile ) {
        tile.style.WebkitTransform = 'none';
        tile.style.transform = 'none';
    } );
}

BoxesFx.prototype._resizeHandler = function() {
    var self = this;
    function delayed() {
        self._resize();
        self._resizeTimeout = null;
    }
    if ( this._resizeTimeout ) {
        clearTimeout( this._resizeTimeout );
    }
    this._resizeTimeout = setTimeout( delayed, 50 );
}

BoxesFx.prototype._resize = function() {
    win.width = getViewport('x');
    win.height = getViewport('y');
    this._setTransforms();
}

// add to global namespace
window.BoxesFx = BoxesFx;
```

} )( window );
`

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Reference https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<style>
.mySlides {display:none;}
</style>
<body>

<h2 class="w3-center">Automatic Slideshow</h2>

<div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:500px">
  <img class="mySlides" src="img_la.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="img_ny.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="img_chicago.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<script>
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for the help but it was not helpful can you plz see the new code which i have updated

Answer (score 0):

Try with `setInterval` function.`i = i++ % 2` it will control the navctrl 0 and 1

```
BoxesFx.prototype._initEvents = function() {
    var self = this, navctrls = this.nav.children;
    // previous action
    navctrls[0].addEventListener( 'click', function() { self._navigate('prev') } );
    // next action
    navctrls[1].addEventListener( 'click', function() { self._navigate('next') } );
    // window resize
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', function() { self._resizeHandler(); } );
    var i=0;
    setInterval(function(){
    navctrls[i].trigger('click')
   i = i++ % 2
    },1000)
}
```